# Xwiki automatically increment number page title in Application

Tags: velocity, xwiki

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxfuf.png)

Hi
I would like to add an automatic increment to the head of my application.
For example; "Permission Certificate #1", "Permission Certificate #2", "Permission Certificate #3" etc ...
How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry,image not uploaded.Image here --> https://yadi.sk/i/_ZdFSglW3ZTAen

Comment: Link not working...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/UIN%20Script%20Service

It would be nice if that extension would be improved to support specifying multiple unique groups and not have just a single, common one, but it’s still something that might ensure you get a thread safe incremental number.

You could also mix it with some JavaScript so that, when the "Add New Entry" button is pressed, you call a page that gets you the new number or the entire new name that you auto-fill in the page name input and submit it directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{velocity }}
#set($space = "ITB.İZİN BELGESİ OLUŞTUR")

#set($index = $xwiki.queryManager.xwql("select max(exp.index) from Document doc, doc.object(ITB.Code.ITBClass) as exp").execute())

#if($index.size() < 1 || !$index[0])
  #set($index = 1)
  #set($index = $index.longValue())
#else
  #set($index = $index[0] + 1)
#end

#set($newDoc = $xwiki.getDocument("$space.$index"))
#set($report = $newDoc.getObject('ITB.Code.ITBClass', true))

#set($header="İzin Belgesi $index")
$newDoc.setTitle($header)

$report.set('index', $index)
$newDoc.save()

$response.sendRedirect($xwiki.getURL($newDoc, 'edit'))
{{/velocity }}
```

Thanks Eduard.I wrote this code and made the auto incrementing numbered heading

Comment: There seems to be no problem with this code fragment.